# Sudden change in the Code Completion in Netbeans 8.0- I could not have it for xhtml files, a unique option of data-bind appears

Tags: netbeans, code-completion

Without aparent reason i can not get code completion in xhtml files anymore, instead i get a unique option: data-bind

Is this because an update in the plugins?
How can I reset the previous behaviour of the code completion?

Answer (score 0):

Some of the JS editor plugins seem to mess around with JSF completion since 8.0.2.
Deactivating the plugins restored normal JSF code completion for me.
Go to "Tools->Plugins" and deactivate the plugins in the "Editing" category. In my case that was "Knockout" and "AngularJS".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Deactivated the openshift plugin, restarted IDE and it works now.